# Cannot click on the element using Cypress

Tags: cypress

I click on the input field and popup with items list appears. But I cannot click on any item

```
cy.get('#field')
  .click({force:true})   //popup with items list appers

cy.get('.ant-select-dropdown-menu')
  .should('be.visible')
  .contains('Item123', { timeout: 20000})
  .click({force:true})
```

Error:

```
Timed out retrying: Expected to find content: 'Item123' within the element: <ul.ant-select-dropdown-menu> but never did.
```

I use this html.
I click on the field and popup appears with items list. I want to click on the any item.
html:

```
 <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%;">
     <div>
         <div class="ant-select-dropdown  ant-select-dropdown-hidden" style="width: 180px; left: 883px; top: 477px;">
             <div id="753a81bb-579c-4483-f7e5-5527f7c01f3a" style="overflow: auto; transform: translateZ(0px);">
               <ul role="listbox" class="ant-select-dropdown-menu  ant-select-dropdown-menu-root ant-select-dropdown-menu-vertical" tabindex="0">
                 <li role="option" unselectable="on" class="ant-select-dropdown-menu-item" aria-selected="false" style="user-select: none;">
                  Item1 <i aria-label="icon: check" class="anticon anticon-check ant-select-selected-icon"></i>
                 </li>
                 <li role="option" unselectable="on" class="ant-select-dropdown-menu-item" aria-selected="false" style="user-select: none;">
                     Item12 <i aria-label="icon: check" class="anticon anticon-check ant-select-selected-icon"></i>
                 </li>
                 <li role="option" unselectable="on" class="ant-select-dropdown-menu-item" aria-selected="false" style="user-select: none;">
                     Item123 <i aria-label="icon: check" class="anticon anticon-check ant-select-selected-icon"></i>
                 </li>
                 <li role="option" unselectable="on" class="ant-select-dropdown-menu-item" aria-selected="false" style="user-select: none;">
                     Item1234 <i aria-label="icon: check" class="anticon anticon-check ant-select-selected-icon"></i>
                 </li>
               </ul>
             </div></div></div>
```

Comment: Is “ant...” a classname? If so, doesn’t it need a “.” in front of it?

Comment: I forgot  ".", the problem is present.Why do you post minus?

Comment: I didn't downvote, others probably did because you didn't post the actual code you're testing against - so we can't reproduce the problem ourselves. Looks like the `.` got us closer! Are you sure there's a string `Item123` in the menu? Can you share some code?

Comment: @JBallin   I add html code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [eq()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/eq.html#Syntax) to get DOM element at a specific index in an array of elements:

```
cy.get('li.ant-select-dropdown-menu-item', {
  timeout: 20000
}).eq(2).click({
  force: true
})
```